# Java TCP Client freezes when creating output / input streams?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, stream

I'm not sure what's going on here.
I've got a TCP java server that waits for incoming connections.

In my TCP java client, I'm trying to make it so when I press the "connect" button on my GUI form, (when connect() is called in TCPClient.java), it opens up a new socket to the server.

This works, the server correctly displays that a new player joins when I press "connect" on the client.

Now I need the client to be able to have an input stream and an output stream to send/receive data on. I will do this on a separate thread. However when I create these 2 streams, the program completely freezes.

I don't want my program to freeze when I create the stream, because then it can't get to the point where I make my ListenFromServer thread:

```
    package client;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;


    public class TCPClient extends Thread {
        UIClient ui;
        public boolean connected = false;
        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream sInput;       // to read from the socket
        ObjectOutputStream sOutput;     // to write on the socket


        public TCPClient(UIClient ui) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
            this.ui = ui;
            System.out.println("client start");
            ui.console.println("CLIENT TEST");
        }

        public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
            try{
                socket = new Socket("localhost", 2232);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                ui.console.println("Could not connect to server");
                return;
            }
            try{
            sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            }
            catch (IOException ioE){
                ui.console.println("Exception creating new input/output streams");
                return;
            }
            //Thread that listens for messages from the server
            new ListenFromServer(this).start();
        }
    }
```

It freezes at this try statement:

```
                try{
            sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            }
```

Comment: Its not freezing it's waiting for the connection; java sockets are asynchronous so it is waiting for the connection I would redo the way your starting your using thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489026/what-is-the-main-advantage-of-extending-thread-class-or-when-to-extend-thread-i

How you might want to do it is:
Thread tr = new Thread(new Runabble(){
      void run(){
          while( your socket is connected){
                     TCPClient.this.yourMehtod();
}
}

});

Answer (score 0):

Create the streams in the `run()` method of the thread, not in the `connect()` method that is probably run in the event thread. Creating object streams does I/O. And create the `ObjectOutputStream` first.

Comment: Something is still wrong. After it creates the output stream and outputs: "test 4", the program does not output anything else. All though this time it does not freeze, nothing happens after that.

http://pastie.org/private/ouflcm0yzud4kuzuwfwna

Comment: I won't follow links. Anything that forms part of a question should be posted here: otherwise the question has no permanent value and is liable for deletion. Edit it into question.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectIputStream` will attempt to read from the `input stream` on construction. As the input stream is `blocking` the program will wait until there is something to read.

To resolve this you need to open an `ObjectOutputStream` on the sockets server endpoint.

```
Socket socket = ss.accept(); // ss is the ServerSocket
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Thanks that works but now I can't seem to send data from the server to the newly made client.

I've got a ServerPlayer.java thread which is spawned upon a new connection (socket.accept()), and I pass a new output, input stream and the socket.
Upon the initial starting point of the thread, I write a byte (1):
http://pastie.org/private/haiiqxxvsils7k6zffzmpw

And to receive it, I use my ListenForServer.java class which is a thread on my client that waits for data from server:
http://pastie.org/private/wytv67wivqus0zqz6gb84q

But nothing prints on the client console (line 20 of the second file)

Comment: I suggest you make another question for that.