# Passing a Runnable instance to Thread calls run() of Thread's subclass instead of run() of Runnable class

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have three classes as follows :

1.ThreadInstance

```
public class ThreadInstance extends Thread {
    public ThreadInstance() 
    {
    }
    public ThreadInstance(RunnableInstance r) {
        super(r);
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("|Extend|");
    }
}
```

2.RunnableInstance

```
public class RunnableInstance implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("|Implement|");
    }
}
```

3.Client

```
public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadInstance(new RunnableInstance()).start();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT prints |Extend| instead of |Implement|

In Client class, a thread is created by passing a runnable instance. So when this thread run, run() method of Runnable class(RunnableInstance) should be called. But in the above case, run() method of ThreadInstance is called.

I am not bale to get the reason behind this. Could anyone please put some light on what am i missing here. Also i checked the run() method of Thread class and found that if checks if runnable instance is not null, then it calls run() method from Runnable class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadocs of [`Thread#start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()):

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the `run` method of **this thread**.

So when you call `start()`, the `run` method of `ThreadInstance` gets called.

Note that the *default* `run` method of class `Thread` calls `run` of the target `Runnable` class:

```
// this is the run method of the base Thread class
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

But since you override the `run` method in the subclass `ThreadInstance`, it no longer calls the target `RunnableInstance`.

Comment: dumb me... :) How could i miss that. Thanks btw.

Comment: @AR.3: is that code block ("this is the run method ...") directly from the Java source code?

Answer (score 3):

> i checked the run() method of Thread class and found that […] it calls run() method from Runnable class

You've overrided the `run` method so that your `ThreadInstance` no longer does this.

You need to pick one or the other. *Either* override `run` in `Thread` *or* pass it a `Runnable`. Not both.

*Technically speaking*, one could do the following:

```
public class ThreadInstance extends Thread {
    public ThreadInstance() {}
    public ThreadInstance(RunnableInstance r) { super(r); }

    public void run() {
        super.run(); // note
        System.out.println("|Extend|");
    }
}
```

But that is probably not a good idea unless you really know what you are doing. We generally shouldn't change the behavior of `Thread`.

See also:

- ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)
- [What is the main advantage of extending Thread class (or when to extend Thread instead of implement runnable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489026/what-is-the-main-advantage-of-extending-thread-class-or-when-to-extend-thread-i)
- [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Answer (score 0):

You've overiden the `run` method of the thread class and you never call the super implementation, hence, the runnable never gets called.

You don't need to override the thread at all but if you must, you should, sometime, call `super.run()` within your `run` implementation.