# Android: What does posting a runnable from another thread onto the main thread actually do?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So, as the title says: What actually happens when you post a runnable from another thread onto the main thread?

I've seen lots of questions asking how you do it, and how the basics of it work. But I've had a hard time finding an exact explanation of what actually happens when you put a runnable on the MessageQueue. It runs when it is the Runnable's turn, sure. But when is this?

So for example:
Assuming that there's a button that launches an ASync request, and the request returns and triggers a runnable/callback that runs on the MainThread. What happens? The runnable gets added to a MessageQueue and runs when it is 'time'. But when is it 'time'? What if I press another button that does some semi-long blocking task on the MainThread just before the Async request posts the runnable on MainThread? Does it wait until the logic on my blocking button is completed? Does it interrupt it? Does it interweave the runnable code with the code of my blocking-code button? What happens exactly?

Main reason I'm asking is so I can get a better understanding of what considerations I need to keep in mind to prevent errors due to multithreading. (Specifically the case of old requests affecting pages that have already been refreshed)

Comment: I think the mainthread task is run one by one .. post runnable to mainthread is just put it after the doing task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to understand what the `Message` class is like. A `Message` object contains among other fields the following:

```
    Handler target;     // a handler that enqueued the message
    long when;          // the time at which the message is to be processed 

    [RUNNABLE] Runnable callback;   =
    [SWITCHED] int what, int arg1, int arg2, Bundle data...

    bool isAsynchronous; // I will talk about it in the end
```

What I tagged with *[RUNNABLE]* and *[SWITCHED]*  represents the two non-overlapping means of processing a `Message`. If the `callback` is not null all the *[SWITCHED]* fields are ignored. If the `callback` is null than the `Message` is defined by *[SWITCHED]* fields and is processed in either the `Handler's` overriden `handleMessage()` or the `handleMessage()` of the `Handler.Callback` the handler was initialized with.

The `MessageQueue` is sorted by the `when` field. The `Looper` will not dequeue and process a message until the current time, as measured by `SystemClock.uptimeMillis`, is greater than or equal to the time stored in the message’s `when` field.

When you call `Handler#post(Runnable r)` the following things happen:

1. A `Message` is obtained from the pool (a simple static linked list
   in the `Message` class)
2. Your `Runnable` is assigned to the message's `callback` field.
3. `when` field is simply set to the current time if no delay or specific
   time was passed
4. The `Message` is enqueued to the `MessageQueue`. If `when` is
   earlier than that of the head of the queue it becomes a new head. If
   it's not, than it's inserted in the middle so that the `MessageQueue`
   remains sorted by `when`
5. The `Looper` which was in a non-terminating loop dequeuing the messages
   from the queue and processing them in sequence (no interweaving),
   eventually, dequeues our message and calls `dispatchMessage()` on
   the handler that originally posted the `Runnable`.
6. The handler decides whether the message is *[RUNNABLE]* or
   *[SWITCHED]* and processes it accordingly. In particular it calls
   `run()` on the `callback` if it's present

This should answer your questions on the behavior of your `Runnable` posted on the UI Thread during the blocking task - well, **no, it does not interrupt the ongoing task, nor does it interweave**. Everything that happens on the thread first gets into the `MessageQueue`, button clicks or your custom `Runnables` that you post from other threads. There is basically no way it could be happening some other way: `Looper.loop()` just makes the thread busy with its `for(;;)` loop.

**There are ways to change the messages ordering though.**

For instance, there is an interesting concept of sync-barrier in the Looper/Handler framework. A sync-barrier is by a convention just a `Message` with a null `target` (so it's basically just a flag-like thing, there is no handler to dispatch it). If it's put to the queue with `postSyncBarrier()`, the whole process of dequeuing changes, until the sync-barrier is removed from the queue with `removeSyncBarrier()`. The `Messages` not marked as `isAsynchronous` will be ignored and not dequeued and processed at all. Instead, the queue will be scanned until the message with `isAsynchronous = true` is found. It will then be scheduled according to its `when` and processed when its time comes.

Also, you can call a self-explanatory `Handler#postAtFrontOfQueue()`, though, as pointed out in the documentation

> This method is only for use in very special circumstances -- it can
>   easily starve the message queue, cause ordering problems, or have
>   other unexpected side-effects.

I suggest you browse the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/47fb191/core/java/android/os/Handler.java) of all the classes mentioned. It reads like a good fiction book.

Comment: Super detailed answer! Where were you when I asked this question 2 years ago? :') Thanks a lot.

Comment: Two years ago I wasn't programming for Android :) You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of other runnables that the MainThread executes, such as updating the UI, touch events. The 'time' is when the posted runnable is ready to be dequeued. If any other runnable came before it, your runnable will wait.

There is no such thing here as interruption. Your button will submit burst of runnables, as same as submitting same number of runnables from many different threads.

If you have a message that is non-short (whatever contains LONG word is bad for UI) operation will block the execution of other recurrent tasks submitted in the queue, most of often demonstrated with no updates (for task that execution is indeterminate) on the UI at all or junking if it is matter of burst of runnables that execution takes longer than 8ms.

Comment: Do you have any references for this? It seems very interesting and I wonder where the exact numbers come from, etc.

Comment: I'm assuming that the listeners for every one of these events get wrapped in one big runnable when they are triggered? Or are there also cases where the system tries to split our own-written code up in multiple runnables to 'share' time with other runnables? If so, is there any way to see how this system works?

Comment: @ZeroStatic 1st question, short answer No. Long: I'm not quite sure how events are pipelined. 2nd question: No it does not split, maybe on linux kernel does this. 3rd question: See the source of `MessageQueue` how runnables are queued for execution.

@Acapulco, I'm just interpreting the source and this diagram http://i.imgur.com/EIOk5Gq.png