# Post a Runnable to another thread in plain java

Tags: java, multithreading

In Android we have Handler#post(Runnable) method to post some code to the main thread from another

Is it possible to make same thing in plain java (for instance while using swing)?

Explaining the question:
Assume we have two threads: ThreadA and ThreadB. Both are started already and running side-by-side. And ThreadB wants ThreadA to invoke some method (again, ThreadA is already running).

Addition optional question (you may not answer it):
And if it's possible, someone explain me how does exactly Handler do in Android. How it's able to post some code to MainThread? What is a purpose of the Looper?

Comment: Please post a more concrete example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: GV, no, I don't do Android programming, but I do do a lot of Swing coding, including working with background threads.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Did you work with Android? There is a class Handler. Usage is simple: new Hanldler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() { void run() {}}); Dosen't matter what thread is current now, the run() method will be invoked only in MainThread.

Comment: For Handlers **ThreadLocal, Thread, Looper** follwed by **Handler** study these three concepts along with as how Thread.java uses a map structure to associate value set by thread local object. You will really have a good learning expierence if you dive into above topics. These cover the concept of Handler internal working. While studying above 1. Why handler object cant be created in a thread not having a looper object with it 2. How looper object gets accociated with current thread 3. What and how does Looper.prepare() does and finally about Looper.loop() method

Comment: *"how does exactly Handler do in Android"* - Without knowing the specifics of how the API works, I would suggest that `Handler#post` places the `Runnable` on a queue, which the "main thread" processes, when it "pops" a `Runnable` off the queue, it simply calls the `Run` method

Comment: @nits.kk Thanks a lot. I will read about those concepts. As I understood in Android threads don't touch each other. It's only a loop (in MainThread) that invokes all runnables that was written to a field. Am I right?

Comment: I think that you may be looking into using a LinkedBlockingQueue for creating a producer/consumer structure that accepts Runnables or Callables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Addressing your additional question:**

You said "*In Android we have Handler#post(Runnable) method to post some code to the main thread from another*"

It is not exactly correct. You can 'post some code' from any thread A to any thread B provided that thread B is initialized as a `Looper` and the thread A has a reference to a `Handler` for the target thread B.

It is very convenient when you need to do something on the UI thread because the UI thread already has a `Looper` and you can retrieve it from nearly everywhere. The static method `Looper.getMainLooper` is a way to get a `Looper` for the main thread. If you initialize a `Handler` with this `Looper` you can post a `Runnable` or send a `Message` to it (though if you post `Runnable` it also gets wrapped into a `Message`) and it will be executed on the UI thread.

`Looper`, as the name hints, is basically running a non-terminating loop for a thread. The `Looper` has an associated `MessageQueue` which it constantly checks for new `Messages.` Via the `Handler` initialized with a `Looper` you can enqueue `Messages` on this thread. The `Messages` are processed in a sequential order, depending on the `when` field of a `Message`.

Here's a basic implementation of a Looper thread:

```
  class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

I suggest you read the Chapter 5 of **Meike G.B. Android Concurrency**. It will give you a comprehensive insight into the Looper/Handler framework. It is also great to browse the source code while you are reading, it is rather simple and self-explanatory.

Comment: I recently posted an answer to a similar question where I in more detail explain the internals of posting Messages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478689/2611340

Answer (score 0):

Within Swing you would use

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-
```

to run something on the main thread.

In general Java, an ExecutorService is like a thread pool and allows you to submit Runnable or Callable instances

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
```

However, if you aren't using an ExecutorService or Swing, there is no standard Java API to tell another thread to do something.